# Implementing SQL's "not exists" in Silverlight RIA services

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I'm trying to use Silverlight with RIA services. CRUD operations are pretty easy. But I am stuck with the "not exists" case.

I have two entities Person (*personID*, personName) and Car(*carID*, *personID*). Some person have a car, but only one car.

```
 internal sealed class Person
        {
            private PersonMetadata() { }

            public int personID { get; set; }

            public string personName { get; set; }

            [Include]
            public Car CarNavigation  { get; set; }

        }


 internal sealed class Car
        {
            private CarMetadata() { }

            public string carName { get; set; }

            public int personID { get; set; }

        }
```

---

```
    public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonEager()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Person.Include("CarNavigation");
    }
```

---

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="PersonGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns >
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding personID}"  />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding personName}"  />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CarNavigation.carName}"  />
                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                </sdk:DataGrid>


PersonGrid.ItemsSource = context.Person;
context.Load(context.GetPersonEager());
```

This structure works pretty well, for update. I also can update the car's name.

But, I also want to list the persons who does not have a car. And I also want to be able to add cars to them. I have tried:

```
 public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonEagerWhoDoesNotHaveACar()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.Person.Include("CarNavigation").Where( x => x.CarNavigation == null );
        }
```

The method above returns me the persons without cars, but the Car entity is empty. How sould I modify this to make it return the persons without cars and the car entity's key is filled.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want it to return an empty Car entity?

Comment: I want to return a Car entity with its "personID" field is filled and carName is empty. So I can fill it. Since I make a left join while finding the persons without car, I know their (the cars') personID field. So entity framework should know it, too. But the GetPersonEagerWhoDoesNotHaveACar() method returns the persons without car, but I expect the Person.CarNavigation.personID field is filled. Maybe my query is wrong, or maybe EF does not support it or maybe I should do some customizations or maybe I should develop another approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

If "Some person have a car, but only one car" - then you've got wrong DB architecture. Why do not to place nullable carId into `Person`? In such case you'll easily include and manipulate(add, delete etc.) everything you want with or without related `Car`.

*Note: if you steel need such approach with current architecture - then clarify what should return query(list of Persons with Car set to null for not connected items) and for what purpose.*

Comment: I've tried to simplify my actual architecture. I'm sorry but I did not understand what you mean by "add what should return query and for what purpose.".

Comment: @caisenm Ok. I think you've got a problem with relations in edmx. That is why you are stuck with your stuff.